# HTML email signature | Outlook 2013

Tags: html

I have below HTML works for trial [*Screenshot of trial*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3gaZ.jpg) but it does not work when I place into outlook 2013. [*Screenshot of outlook*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7BuQ.jpg) Tried the different codes but still getting the same result. Any help is appreciated!

Cheers

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
 <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <style>
  img { display: block; float: left; padding: 0; align: absbottom; align: texttop; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <tr>
  <td><img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/5x0q3n.jpg"></td>
  


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a reminder, you might not be able to use some CSS syntax because of email client limits. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I guess I will have to make it HTML only friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but from what it looks like your not linking to the raw image file itself.

Try changing the image to this

```
<img src="http://oi64.tinypic.com/5x0q3n.jpg">
```

The current one you have is a redirect

Comment: Thank you NooBskie. I update the correct link and simplified the code as no any fancy coding but it still doesn't work.